# middle crashed returning error of can't set headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I did a simple auth custom middleware but got error. I have no idea what's happending, I thought the next() will solve my problem?

```
    app.use(function(req, res, next){
      if(req.user){
        res.locals.username = req.user.username
      }else{
        res.redirect('/login');
      }

  next();
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login');
});
```

my error

```
_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `next` is called even if `req.user` is falsy because execution doesn't stop after calling `res.redirect`, `next` attempts to set headers after `res.redirect` has sent out response so just replace that with `return res.redirect('/login')` and you should be good to go.

**EDIT** in this case the middleware is running on each route, causing a loop issue because the login route needs to be authenticated too, that can be fixed like this.

```
function auth(req, res, next) {
    // authenticate and call next or redirect
}

router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});

router.get('/authentic', auth, function(req, res) {
    // body
});
```

Comment: tried what you said. I got this error. This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: The problem is the authentication middleware you wrote is application wide, so it runs before the login route too causing the loop, so you have to make it so that it only runs on routes that need to be authenticated like so
    function auth(req, res, next) {//body}

    router.get('/login', auth, function(req, res) {
        res.render('login');
    }

Comment: apparently i am not able to edit my comment so i will update the answer to resolve your issue.

Comment: so what if I enter /dashboard, I still have to call auth?

Comment: yeah, you have to add the `auth` middleware to all the routes that need authentication.